# Return ID value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple table arranged as below and I'd like to write a query that returns the single client_id that has most transactions. One client has most transactions than any other client in the table.

```
transaction_id int 
client_id int 
comments varchar
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method for obtaining the data by counting the rows, grouping on the client_id and then filtering for top 1 ordered by the count descending.

```
declare @table table (
    transaction_id int,
    client_id int,
    comments varchar(20)
);

insert into @table (transaction_id, client_id, comments)
values
(1, 1, ''),
(2, 2, ''),
(3, 2, ''),
(4, 3, '')

    select top 1 client_id, count(*) as vol
    from @table
    group by client_id
    order by vol desc
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it for you:

```
SELECT client_id FROM table_name GROUP BY client_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select client_id, count(transaction_id)
from table
group by client_id
order by 2 desc
limit 1;
```

`Group by` helps to gather records based on a particular column and the `count`returns the number of records corresponding to that column value. `Order by` desc arranges in descending order and `limit 1` restricts to 1 record.